# Error running kubelet, node not ready

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running kuberentes using docker and I am able to run a pod, it goes into running stage after some time it goes to pending

kubelet logs show this:

```
E1027 02:52:53.222558   21724 kubelet.go:2246] Error updating node status, will retry: node "127.0.0.1" cannot be updated: the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
I1027 02:53:06.230423   21724 kubelet.go:2255] Recording NodeReady event message for node 127.0.0.1
```

and then node becomes not ready. Then I have to restart kubeblet and everything runs fine for a while, then again kubelet expires. Any idea why am I having this issue? Why is kubelet saying node not ready again and again?

TIA.

Update:
There are also these type of logs:

```
E1027 03:23:00.659237   17690 volumes.go:152] Could not read directory /var/lib/kubelet/pods/34aa25b8-763b-11e5-9d79-5252c7a37a40/volumes: open /var/lib/kubelet/pods/34aa25b8-763b-11e5-9d79-5252c7a37a40/volumes: no such file or directory
E1027 03:23:00.659359   17690 volumes.go:152] Could not read directory /var/lib/kubelet/pods/91cc7728-763b-11e5-9d79-5252c7a37a40/volumes: open /var/lib/kubelet/pods/91cc7728-763b-11e5-9d79-5252c7a37a40/volumes: no such file or directory
E1027 03:23:00.659419   17690 volumes.go:152] Could not read directory /var/lib/kubelet/pods/ebea235e-765e-11e5-b350-525400698cc6/volumes: open /var/lib/kubelet/pods/ebea235e-765e-11e5-b350-525400698cc6/volumes: no such file or directory
E1027 03:23:00.659597   17690 volumes.go:152] Could not read directory /var/lib/kubelet/pods/34aa25b8-763b-11e5-9d79-5252c7a37a40/volumes: open /var/lib/kubelet/pods/34aa25b8-763b-11e5-9d79-5252c7a37a40/volumes: no such file or directory
E1027 03:23:00.660461   17690 volumes.go:152] Could not read directory /var/lib/kubelet/pods/91cc7728-763b-11e5-9d79-5252c7a37a40/volumes: open /var/lib/kubelet/pods/91cc7728-763b-11e5-9d79-5252c7a37a40/volumes: no such file or directory
E1027 03:23:00.660906   17690 volumes.go:152] Could not read directory /var/lib/kubelet/pods/ebea235e-765e-11e5-b350-525400698cc6/volumes: open /var/lib/kubelet/pods/ebea235e-765e-11e5-b350-525400698cc6/volumes: no such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs about this?

Comment: @cristi: Yeah, I found some more stuff, have updated in the question

Comment: What is the output of "ls -la /var/lib/kubelet/" and "ps -elf | grep kubelet"

Comment: Can you run `kubectl describe node <node_name>` to see why kubelet transitioned to not ready?